# Code Signing a file using Apple certificates

Tags: xcode, macos, openssl, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I wish to sign a .mobileconfig file using a p12 file. I exported the P12 file using the Keychain Access panel on MacOS. (Developer ID Application).

Generate Private Key:

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl pkcs12 -in my.p12 -nocerts -out private.pem
```

Generate Certificate:

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl pkcs12 -in my.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out cert.pem
```

Sign the File:

```
 C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl smime -sign -signer cert.pem -inkey private.pem -nodetach -outform der -in test.mobileconfig -out test-signed.mobileconfig
```

Horrible error message:

```
 Loading 'screen' into random state - done
 unable to load signing key file
 9124:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
 unable to write 'random state'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Check with an ascii editor the private key file. Where is the password?

Comment: This particular pem has no password. Or at least the password is blank.

Comment: How can you sign with a private key if you do have a private key?